# Surface area of a multi-dimensional cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I denote a point $x \in \mathbb R ^{n+1}= (x_1, \ldots ,x_n , x_{n+1})=(x^\prime, x_{n+1}).$ Let me consider a multi-dimensional cone $\mathcal {C}_a$ in $\mathbb R ^{n+1}$  as the set $$\mathcal {C}_a= \{x \in \mathbb R ^{n+1}: x_{n+1}> a |x^\prime | \}, $$ where $|x^\prime |= (x_1^2+ \ldots +x_n^2)^{1/2} $, and $a$ is a positive constant (I think there is another definition by means of matrices).

What is the $n$-dimensional surface area of $E_{a,t}= \mathcal {C}_a \cap \{x: 0\le x_{n+1} \leq t \} $? Strictly speaking,  I mean $\mathcal H ^n (\partial E_{a,t})$, where $\mathcal H ^n$ is the Hausdorff (=surface) measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $E_{a,t}$ has a "rim"  at height $t$ over the $x'$-plane. This rim is an $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere of radius $r(t)=t/a$. Let $\omega_{n-1}$ be the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, hence $\omega_1=2\pi$ and $\omega_2=4\pi$.

Assume that $t$ is increased to $t+dt$. Then $\partial E_{a,t}$ increases by two annular pieces of surface: A plane annulus of area $$\omega_{n-1}r^{n-1}(t)\bigl(r(t+dt)-r(t)\bigr)=\omega_{n-1}\left({t\over a}\right)^{n-1}\>{dt\over a}\ ,\tag{1}$$ and a conical annulus of an  area obtained by introducing a pythagorean factor $\sqrt{1+1/a^2}$ in $(1)$.

If the surface area of $E_{a,t}$ is denoted by $\sigma(t)$ then we see that
$$\sigma(t+dt)-\sigma(t)={\omega_{n-1}\over a^n}\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/a^2}\right) t^{n-1}\>dt\ ,$$
and this leads to
$$\sigma(t)={\omega_{n-1}\over n\> a^n}\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/a^2}\right)\>t^n\ .$$

Comment: It really makes sense. Thank you so much! I enjoyed it as a nice calculus job. @christianblatter